# Friendbot bad request (400) invalid_field: "addr"

Tags: accounts, javascript-sdk, friendbot

I am trying to create an account on the stellar Test Network. But whenever I make a request and pass in the public key, I always get this error:
[image]
I am using the Javascript documentation from [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the URL, you pass "${encodeURIComponent...}" as a string, not as evaluated value. Your code is probably something like:

```
url = 'https://friendbot(...)?addr=${encodeURIComponent...}';
```

but should be like:

```
url = 'https://friendbot(...)?addr=' + encodeURIComponent...;
// or as a template string
url = `https://friendbot(...)?addr=${encodeURIComponent...}`;
```

...and since the public keys do not contain special characters, it's not neccessary to escape it.

```
url = 'https://friendbot(...)?addr=' + pair.publicKey();
```